# Is the identiy function continous on equivalent metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f$ be the identity function from $(X,d_1) \to (X,d_2)$.  If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent metrics we can deduce that the identity function is continuous, right?

Since for every open set $G$, its pre-image under $f$ would also be $G$, and since the metrics are equivalent an open set in one metric is open in the other?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Yes. In fact, the identity function is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In fact, the following criterion is useful:

> The identity function $f:(X,d_1)\to (X,d_2)$ is continuous if and only
>   if for all $x\in X$ and for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$
>   such that $x\in B_{d_1}(x,\delta)\subseteq B_{d_2}(x,\epsilon)$.
>   ($B_{d_i}(x,r)$ denotes the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$ with
>   respect to the metric $d_i$ on $X$.)

In particular, the condition that the identity function be continuous is weaker than the condition that $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ be equivalent metric spaces. The latter condition is equivalent to the assertion that the identity function *and* the inverse of the identity function are continuous.

***Exercise 1***: Prove the criterion stated above using the definition of continuity via open sets.

***Exercise 2***: Let $d_1$ be the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by the rule $d_1(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ and $d_1(x,x)=0$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $d_2$ be the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that the identity function $f:(\mathbb{R},d_1)\to (\mathbb{R},d_2)$ is continuous. However, prove that the identity function $g:(\mathbb{R},d_2)\to (\mathbb{R},d_1)$ is *not* continuous!

***Exercise 3***: Let $d_1$ be the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $d_2$ be the metric defined by the rule $d_2(x,y)=\text{min} \{1,d_1(x,y)\}=\text{min} \{1,\left|x-y\right|\}$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent metrics on $\mathbb{R}$ and verify independently that both the identity function $f:(\mathbb{R},d_1)\to (\mathbb{R},d_2)$ and its inverse $g:(\mathbb{R},d_2)\to (\mathbb{R},d_1)$ are continuous.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

To say that the metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent amounts to saying that, if ${\mathcal T}_1$ and ${\mathcal T}_2$ are the topologies generated by them, then ${\mathcal T}_1 = {\mathcal T}_2$.

Let $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ be two topologies on some space $X$.  (For example $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ could be the topologies generated by the metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$, respectively, but the points made below apply more generally.)

Also, let $I$ be the map $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)\to (X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ defined by $x \mapsto x$. <sup>1</sup>

Now, the following four statements are absolutely equivalent; they differ only in clarity or directness.  Take your pick:

1. $\mathcal{T}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_1$;
2. for all $U \in \mathcal{T}_2$, the set $I^{-1}(U) = U$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}_1$;
3. for any open set $U$ in $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$, the preimage $I^{-1}(U)$ is open in $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$;
4. the map $I$ (as defined above) is *continuous*.

Now, clearly, the map $I$ is bijective, and therefore its inverse $I^{-1}:(X, \mathcal{T}_2)\to (X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ is a well-defined map.  This means that the duals of the four statements above are also equivalent to each other; these four equivalent statements are:

1. $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$;
2. for all $U \in \mathcal{T}_1$, the set $I(U) = U$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}_2$;
3. for any open set $U$ in $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$, the the image of $U$ under $I$ is open in $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$;
4. the inverse $I^{-1}$ of the bijection $I$ (as defined above) is *continuous*.

Next, we have the following two equivalent statement, the first obtained by combining the first statements of the two sets above, and the second by combining the last ones:

1. $\mathcal{T}_1 = \mathcal{T}_2$;
2. the bijection $I$ (given by $x \mapsto x$) is *homeomorphic*.

And, as already pointed out before, in the special case where ${\mathcal T}_1$ and ${\mathcal T}_2$ are the topologies generated by the metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$, respectively, the last two statements are also equivalent to:

3. the metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent.

So, as others have pointed out, the equivalence of the two metrics renders the map $x\mapsto x$ not only continuous, but in fact homeomorphic.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I'm refraining from calling $I$ the "identity" out of pedantry...  Strictly speaking, the domain and codomain of the *identity* are the same, while here we're treating the domain $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ and codomain $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ of $I$ as distinct *topological spaces* (even if they both have the same "underlying *set*" $X$).  The "function of sets underlying" the map $I$ is certainly the identity $X \to X$.  I don't like all this fuss more than anyone else, but when one starts talking about "equivalent metrics", etc., it's difficult to escape such pedantry altogether.</sub>

Comment: The question was more specifically about *metrics*. The topological story was also discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/79513/6490).