# Is $f(n)=n$, where $n\in \mathbb Z$ with the Euclidean metric continuous on $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

According to the definition of continuity, given any $n_0\in \mathbb Z$, $\forall \epsilon\gt0$, $\exists\delta>0$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb Z$ and $d_X(n,n_0)\lt \delta \Rightarrow d_Y\bigl(f(n),f(n_0)\bigl)\lt \epsilon$ holds when $\delta=\epsilon$. So I conclude that this graphically discrete function is continuous... Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Since the space is discrete itself, this is not so weird.

Comment: Thank you guys!

Comment: Unless you put two different metrics on domain and codomain, it is continuous. However (I strongly believe) you still can come up with different $d_X, d_Y$ so that $1_{\mathbb{N}}$ is discontinuous.

Comment: [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054874/give-two-examples-of-metrics-to-make-identity-function-discontinuous)

Comment: Every function $\mathbb  Z\to X$ from $\mathbb Z$ with the Euclidean metric to another metric space $X$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You can always take $\delta=1$, as $d_X(n,n') < 1$ implies $n=n'$ for $n,n' \in \Bbb Z$ and then the $f$-values are the same.