# Understanding equivalent metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

I have studied following definitions of equivalent metric spaces.

Two metrics on a set $X$ are said to be equivalent if and only if they induce the same topology on $X$.

1:  Two metrices $d_1$ and $d_2$ in metric space $X$ are equivalent if $d_1(x_n,x_0)\rightarrow 0 $ iff $d_2(x_n,x_0)\rightarrow 0 $.

2: We say that d1 and d2 are equivalent iff there exist positive constants $c$ and $C$
such that
$c d_1(x, y)\leq d_2(x, y)\leq Cd_1(x, y)$ for all $x, y \in X$.

My questions are as follows:

Is there any other definition of equivalent metrics? I need a proof of how these conditions are equivalent?

Is there any connection between homeomorphism and equivalence of metric spaces?

What are the common properties shared by equivalent metric spaces?

I am very much confused with this. Quite often I found myself struggling with what definition  should I apply to show the equivalence of given metric spaces. I need help to clear my doubts.

Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: The conditions 1. and 2. are not equivalent. 1. expresses that $d_1$ and $d_2$ have the same closed sets. 2. expresses that $d_1$ and $d_2$ have the same Cauchy sequences (and more). Property 2. implies property 1. The metrics $d_1(x,y) = |x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y) = \min\{1,|x-y|\}$ on $X = \mathbb{R}$ are equivalent in first sense but not in the second sense. A third sense (in between 1 and 2) is mentioned [in this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5315/5363).

Comment: In this [Wiki aritcle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics) property one is called equivalence while property is called *strong equivalence*.

Comment: A compact overview may be found on: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/370928056_Equivalence_of_metrics_a_comparison

Comment: @AfterMath Thank you so much. I will go through it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer to "Is there any connection between homeomorphism and equivalence of metric spaces?" is yes. The long answer: any reasonable notion of equivalence of two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ can be formulated in terms of the *identity map* $\mathrm{id}\colon (X,d_1)\to (X,d_2)$. As soon as we distinguish a class of "nice" maps (the class should be a group under composition), we get a notion of equivalence. Some examples, previously mentioned and not:

1. $\mathrm{id}$ is a [homeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)
2. $\mathrm{id}$ is a [uniform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_isomorphism) homeomorphism (i.e., uniformly continuous with a uniformly continuous inverse)
3. $\mathrm{id}$ is a [bilipschitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_function) homeomorphism (i.e., Lipschitz with a Lipschitz inverse)
4. $\mathrm{id}$ is a [quasisymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasisymmetric_map) homeomorphism
5. $\mathrm{id}$ is an [isometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_isomorphism)
6. $\mathrm{id}$ is a [quasi-isometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry)

... The list is not exhaustive.

The corresponding notions of equivalence are related by $5\implies 3\implies 2\implies 1$, also $3\implies 4\implies 1$, and $3\implies 6$.

Answer (score 5):

Two definitions on equivalence are not the same. Definition 2 implies definition 1, but not vice versa.

For instance, Let $X = (0, 1]$ and $d_1(x, y) = |x - y|$ and $d_2(x, y) = |\frac 1 x - \frac 1 y|$. Then $d_1$ is equivalent to $d_2$ under Def-1, but not under Def-2. Indeed, one can see $X$ is complete under $d_1$, but not $d_2$.

Comment: This is a great example for: ["A metric that is strongly equivalent (definition 2) to a complete metric is also complete; the same is not true of equivalent metrics (definition 1) because *homeomorphisms* do not preserve completeness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Properties_preserved_by_equivalence).

Comment: Pardon if it's trivial but is $X$ complete under $d_1$, can't we find a cauchy sequence that doesn't converge in $(0, 1]$?