# Relationship between complete metrics

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Sorry that my question is a bit vague.  I have a space $X$ and two metrics that are both complete and induce the same topology on $X$.
Certainly the metrics do not need to be Lipschitz equivalent, but is there any other reasonable definition to say that the metrics are "basically" equivalent?

Are they actually "basically" equivalent?  -- in the sense "is there maybe a meaningful property of one metric that does hold for the other one"?

Let me illustrate where my problem stems from:  As I read, one of the standard ways to define the space of Sobolev maps between two manifolds $M$ and $N$ is by embedding the target manifold $N$ by $\iota$ into an $\mathbb{R}^n$ for large $n$.  We then say that a map $u\colon M \to N$ is Sobolev if $\iota\circ u\colon M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is Sobolev in the classical sense.  It is also clear that the Sobolev norm on $W^{k,p}(M;\mathbb{R}^n)$ induces a nice distance function on the space of Sobolev maps between $M$ and $N$.

I was trying to show that this definition does not depend on the choice of the embedding $\iota\colon M \to N$ used.  I do manage to prove that neither the space itself nor the topology depend on this choice, but unfortunately the resulting distance functions are different and in fact not even bi-Lipschitz.

I guess my proper question is:  What notion of equivalence intermediate between "induce the same topology" and "bi-Lipschitz" should I be looking for -- I do believe that the metrics should be similar -- for example all metrics are clearly complete...

Thank you.

Comment: Two metrics are *by definition* equivalent if they induce the same topology.  On the other hand, two equivalent metrics needn't be the same---perhaps bi-Lipschitz equivalence or isometric equivalence are more what you are looking for?

Comment: The supremum metric and the standard metric both induce the same topology on $\mathbb R^n$ but one is a Banach space and the other is a Hilbert space. Are they the same?

Comment: As topological spaces? Yes.  One is an inner product space and the other isn't but they have the same open sets.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for your answer.  Indeed I was assuming that the standard definition of equivalence between metrics would be the identity is bi-Lipschitz (just as for normed vector spaces) while inducing the same topology seems much too weak since this does not even preserve completeness.
I found this post [Notions of equivalent metrics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5315/notions-of-equivalent-metrics)  describing a third definition "metrically equivalent".  I will think if this is what I'm interested in.