# Do equivalent induced metrics conserve completeness?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I know that equivalent metrics do not conserve completeness (e.g $d_1 = |\operatorname{arctan}(x) - \operatorname{arctan}(y)|$ is equivalent to $d_2 = |x - y|$, but $d_1$ does not conserve completeness).

However, equivalent norms do conserve completeness. Does this mean that if two norms are equivalent, their induced metrics are equivalent and they conserve completeness?

Comment: Yes, if two norms are equivalent then (their induced metrics are [(bilipschitz hence uniformly) equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5315/notions-of-equivalent-metrics?rq=1) hence) they conserve completeness. This is what you wrote just before, so what are you asking?